# Migrating from apache2 to vertx 3 when using ssl

Tags: apache, apache2, vert.x

I have to migrate from apache2 httpd to a (java based) vert.x 3 server. An apache2 httpd could successfully be configured using the following three certificate / key files in ssl.conf (shortened paths):

```
<VirtualHost>
  ...

  SSLCertificateFile   certificate.cer
  SSLCertificateKeyFile   privatekey.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile   intermediate.cer

  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Browsers accepted the https connection without complaint.

After creating a keystore for vert.x 3 and running it, the browser tells me:

```
www.mydomain.com uses an invalid security certificate. 
The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate 
is unknown. The server might not be sending the appropriate 
intermediate certificates. 
An additional root certificate may need to be imported. 
Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
```

Yet, the browser seems to receive the right server certificate and intermediate certificate.

How can I find out what root certificate (of severeral GeoTrust root certificates) is used by a well working apache2 httpd configuration? 
Do I have to include that into a java keystore?

If yes, how does httpd find the right root certificate - and where?

Is the .../mozilla folder the right place to fetch root certificates for a server (I think that a place only for certificates for use by the browser)?

To rule out an alternative explanation: Has vertx a known bug in its ssl functionality??

Comment: It would be easier to try to understand the issue if you could provide a simple code example how you configure your SSL in your code.

Comment: What do you mean with "code"? When Vert.x 3 is configured to use a java keystore (.jks), it takes a keystore and a password: new HttpServerOptions()
.setSsl(true)
.setKeyStoreOptions( 
  new JksOptions()
  .setPath("keystore.jks")
  .setPassword("...")
  )
); -- or did you mean by "code" the bash script that uses openssl and keytool to produce a java keystore? <-- that seems to work (intermediate, certificate and key are o.k.) with the exception that the browser gives Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER.

Comment: I wanted to know if you were using keystores or openssl certificates, for example you could use the existing openssl certificates with: `vertx.createHttpServer( new HttpServerOptions() .setSsl(true) .setPemKeyCertOptions( new PemKeyCertOptions() .setKeyPath("server-key.pem") .setCertPath("server-cert.pem")
));`

Comment: @PauloLopes: This might be the shortest path to a solution, I guess! Please post it as answer! To rule out alternative sources of ambiguity I would be thankful if you include in your answer how to create a server-cert.pem from certificate.crt/cer and intermediate.crt/cer. Is it enough to concatenate these into one text file without processing? Most importantly: In which order (servercert first, then intermediate, then root if at all)? Is it necessary to include a root certificate as a third component into server-cert.pem? Is server-key.pem simply a ... .key-file with a renamed ending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vert.x SSL configuration can done using either java `keystores` or using `OpenSSL`. They both have pros and cons, however if you are migrating from `Apache` to `Vert.x` the shortest path would be using the `OpenSSL` engine.

In order to use the `OpenSSL` engine you will need one extra dependency in your project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.33.Fork21</version>
</dependency>
```

This will allow `Netty` to use OpenSSL or more exactly `BoringSSL` and therefore use the existing certificates. Loading certificates is done by creating a `HttpOptions` object like this:

```
new HttpServerOptions()
  .setSsl(true)
  .setPemKeyCertOptions(
    new PemKeyCertOptions()
      .setKeyPath("privatekey.key")
      .setCertPath("certificate.cer")));
```

Key store options configuration expects a private key and its certificate based on Privacy-enhanced Electronic Email (PEM) files.

The key file must contain a non encrypted private key in PKCS8 format wrapped in a PEM block, for example:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDV6zPk5WqLwS0a
...
K5xBhtm1AhdnZjx5KfW3BecE
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The certificate file must contain an X.509 certificate wrapped in a PEM block, for example:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDezCCAmOgAwIBAgIEZOI/3TANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBuMRAwDgYDVQQGEwdV
...
+tmLSvYS39O2nqIzzAUfztkYnUlZmB0l/mKkVqbGJA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

There is no real support for certificate chains but you could work around it (if you have a public facing site) by visiting: https://whatsmychaincert.com/ and downloading the correct chain (keep "Include Root Certificate" unchecked). That download would then become the `certificate.cer`.

Comment: In my case it stll doesn't work. I get an error message: "Missing -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- delimiter", My key starts with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----. When I cancel RSA it doesn't work either. However those keys work fine in apache2.

Comment: The missing part was: $ openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in privatekey.pem -inform pem -out openssl_key_pk8.pem -outform pem -nocrypt. And then 
openssl_key_pk8.pem can be made part of the above procedure.

Comment: Another note, make sure you try to run on oracle jdk since openjdk does not ship with all strong encryption algorithms.